# How to send data from server-side (Express.js) to client-side (React.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

With Express.js, I'am sending a html file containing a React component within.

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res) {

      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
  });
```

For the purposes, let's assume I want to send a unique variable with my html file to every user connecting to localhost:80/index.

How can I send the vatiable from the server-side and how can I retrieve it from the client side ?

Comment: You mean `path.join([__dirname, '/src/index.html'])`

Comment: You should also not serve static files from express, it is bad for the node event loop. Try using a regular web server for that rather an application server. Like nginx, and in production, a CDN.

Comment: So how do you suggest sending a html file containing React code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here.

1. **Use WebSockets.** If you need many, many variables, or they need to be updated live, look at WebSockets; a good library for this is [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)
2. **Specify Some Endpoint to Pass Data.** Perhaps `/api/enviroment`, or something, and make this request as soon as you can. This has the advantage of being able to specify more client side information in your request
3. **Use Cookies.** This is what they were made for (`document.cookie` is your friend)

There are some other methods, but I think that these are the best

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'am already using a lot of Socket.IO in my project but the connection is opened after that I've sent my file so I lose track of the client that I should sent the variable to (As I said, every user is associated to a uniquevariable). Do you know how I can bypass this with Socket.IO? If now, I'll take the Cookies option.

Comment: @Mit Would you be able to keep a registry of users? Or have users send a packet to specify their UID?